# c# Compress File System out of memory

Tags: c#, compression, out-of-memory

I'm developing a service to compress some files and I have been doing tests to the service and it is getting a major failure in bigger files. I'm using an outlook file with 6GB to test and I get an out of memory error after compressing 500Mb.

This is my code:

```
using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(@dir + ZipName, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
    {
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            if (File.GetCreationTime(@dir + file).AddSeconds(FileAge) < DateTime.Now)
            {
                ZipArchiveEntry fileEntry = archive.CreateEntry(file);
                using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fileEntry.Open()))
                {
                    using (FileStream sr = new FileStream(@dir + file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        byte[] block = new byte[1024];
                        int bytesRead = 0;
                        while ((bytesRead = sr.Read(block,0, block.Length)) >0)
                        {
                            writer.Write(block, 0, bytesRead);
                        }
                    }
                }
                File.Delete(@dir + file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideia how I can solve it?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Hm, isn't the maximum file size for a zip file 4GB?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Limits

Comment: Not sure but I think GZipStream could do the trick. I have no such file ready for a test so I can only assume.

Comment: I looked up the specification now, and yes, the limit of a file inside a ZIP is 4GB. However, you can split your input bytes at 4GB...

Comment: I don't know if that will be the problem, my 6gb file was just an example. It crashs at 500 Mb, there will not be files over 2gb so that wont be a problem.

Comment: And why you open it in Update mode? Why not Create?

Comment: It most be a zip per folder, if zip already exists I will just update the current one, otherwise I'm creating one.

Comment: @Vulpex GZip compress ratio isn't that great or I'm doing something wrong

Comment: @JoãoSilva I could be wrong on this one but I think it has even better ratio than zip, though I'm not certain on that, never tested. You can set the Compressionlevel to increase the compression, but that will cost more processing power. Try `CompressionLevel.Optimal`